# whats the difference of these two capture screen codes?

Tags: java, selenium

i have two codes of taking screenshots and i would like to know what is the difference between them?

```
File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);  
FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("C:\\failure.png"));
```

and

```
File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);  
**BufferedImage  fullImg = ImageIO.read(scrFile);**
FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("C:\\failure.png"));
```

so the row with ** ** is the difference but what she does? and why after her i can write:

```
Point point = element.getLocation();

int parkWidth = element.getSize().getWidth();
int parkHeight = element.getSize().getHeight();

BufferedImage eleScreenshot= fullImg.getSubimage(point.getX(), 
point.getY(),parkWidth, parkHeight);
ImageIO.write(eleScreenshot, "png", scrFile);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i have two codes of taking screenshots and i would like to know what is the difference between them?
>   so the row with ** ** is the difference but what she does?

The difference is that in the 2nd code block you define a new variable `fullImg`. However, it is not used so those 2 code blocks are the same (for capturing the screenshot).

> and why after her i can write:

This is because you have defined the variable `fullImg` and are then using it:

```
BufferedImage eleScreenshot= fullImg.getSubimage(point.getX(), point.getY(),parkWidth, parkHeight);
```

Whereas in the first code block you don't have `fullImg` and thus this would error out.

Comment: thanks, 
so actualy for capturing the screenshot, theres no need for the BufferedImage , the only need for it is when theres need to cut image or so, correct?

Comment: @ramzi Yes. You don't need `BufferedImage` for the full screenshot. This should be the accepted answer. +